# Not able to play shared video in mobile but can view in desktop browser

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, sharing

I am using  og:video meta tag to do sharing of video and I can play the video in Facebook newsfeed from desktop browser. However if I view the video from Facebook app, it will not not play the video and it will bring me to the article page.

You can use the Facebook Share feature from https://www.youth.sg/Spotted/People/2017/5/Captured-by-the-journey

Appreciate anyone who can help. Is there any issue with my meta tag?

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=1557722510925076" />

<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />

<meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />

<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />

<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.youth.sg/~/media/YouthSG/behind-the-gram-yk/YK-banner.ashx?w=800&h=450&thn=1" />

<meta property="og:image:width" content="800" />

<meta property="og:image:height" content="450" />

<meta property="og:title" content="Captured by the journey" />
```

Comment: You are supplying a flash video source only ... and flash support on mobile is usually rather thin.

Comment: Any idea how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Supply your own video (surprised that specifying a Facebook video embed URL was even accepted in the first place, usually they exclude stuff that is on their CDN from being used for Open Graph properties such as thumbnails), and supply it as mp4 (plus additionally flash as a second source, if you feel that is still necessary.)

Comment: I can't play youtube video too from facebook mobile app too. Only can view from Desktop. Anyone who know what is wrong with my meta tag?? Urgent.